# stuck in bash after i git to commit,

Tags: git

after $git add . to stage and commit pop up this message.
what does make it happene and how to solve it problem?

in bash

```sh
No commits yet

#       new file:   README.md
#       new file:   app.js
#       new file:   config/auth.js
#       new file:   config/keys.js
```

a link from bash

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   new file:   .gitignore
#   new file:   README.md
#   new file:   app.js
```

Comment: As stated above you might be looking for how to exit the editor. If you want to avoid landing in the editor altogether try `git commit -m "[Your commit message here]"` to avoid being taken to the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You are not stuck in bash, but rather in Vim. You can exit the program without committing by typing `:q!`, if you however want to finish your commit with your entered message, you can always close the program and save your message by typing `:wq`.

I suggest you use `EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano git commit` to use the easier to use texteditor `nano`. You can of course use any other compatible text editor you'd like.